# Scroll to bottom not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need help, why is my scrolltop not working on this [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/c26zd/4/)
I dont know why..using the code everything works fine. But updating the css the scrolltop is not working.:( what should i do to fixed this? is the problem cause by my css style?
i used this but it won't scroll at the bottom of the div..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('scroll must happen');
    $('#message_container').scrollTop($('#message_container')[0].scrollHeight);
    $('.topbox').html('just sample');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no visible scrolling happening because the element you're trying to scroll isn't overflowing; it's all displayed. The scrollbar is for the `<body>` element and not the `<div>` you're trying to scroll.

You can make it work if you give `#message_container` a height e.g.

```css
#message_container {height:100px;}
```

Alternatively, use absolute positioning tricks, for example in [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/529vV/2/). (The *initial* "undoes" CSS, I used it to keep code short. [See MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial))

```css
#container, #head, #body, #foot{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;
}
#head {
    bottom: initial;
    height:50px;
}
/* position so it get's your desired size*/
#body {
    top:50px;
    bottom:50px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
#foot {
    top: initial;
    height:50px;
}
```

Comment: ive updated the link. i add some text to show the overflow but still not working.

Comment: why it was the body tags scroll bar when there was overflow-y set to #message_container?

Comment: @Cindy93 It is `<body>` that is overflowing, not `<div id="message_container">`. The `overflow-y` states explicitly **what** should happen when an _Element_ overflows in the _y-axis_, but it doesn't tell the _Element_ **when** to _overflow_. When to overflow is controlled by height/width restrictions, such as on the _height/widths_ themselves, or other positioning preventing the element growing; such examples include absolute positioning with both _top_ and _bottom_ set.

Comment: well thanks..but i can give a height of 100px on the #message_container.. the i want the height to be flexible.but every message that will appear it should set its focus on the bottom of the div..

Comment: uhmmm.. Paul..just wanna ask..because the head get messed up on iphone..i have a text input on the footer.. once you type and click send the head goes to the center of the page..

Comment: sounds like something else must be going on for the absolute positioning to be re-calculated with different values

Answer (score 0):

You have to set 2 things:

1. Overflow for the div,
2. Some height, even percentage one (to make it more flexible).

If you don't set any height at all the div will expand and then there is nothing to scroll, in this case the only scroll bar you get is of the document itself (body).

I added a height and overflow property to your CSS and now it works as expected.

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c26zd/5/)**

CSS added:

```
#message_container {
 overflow-y:auto;
 overflow-x:hidden;
 height:300px;
}
```